# ListActivity в Android Studio

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Каким образом осуществить переход на другую Activity после нажатия на конкретный элемент списка?

MyActivity.java

```
public class sp extends ListActivity{
final String[] Spisok = new String[]{ "Что", "Как", "Для кого"};
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Spisok);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);;
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position==1){

        }
```

Думаю что-то нужно прописать в условии `if(position==1){}` или есть другие способы? Какие строки добавить в коде?

Comment: Можете написать кастомный адаптер и в нем  повесить листенер на нужный элемент . гуглить CustomAdapter for ListView

Comment: Так же в адаптере можно присваивать каждому элементу ТЭГ view.setTag() и в вашем обработчике можно будет отлавливать не толькло по позиции но и конкретному элементу

Answer (score 1):

Можете почитать про такую штуку как [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), откроете для себя много нового. Конкретно запуск activity происходит так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(_your_context_, SomeActivity.class);
_your_context_.startActivity(intent);
```

Вызывать это, как вы правильно догадались, в

> onListItemClick

Comment: Что означает надпись _your_context_? Выдает ошибку

Comment: Замените на getApplicationContext()

Comment: Последняя часть кода но ошибка в последней строке:                                                                     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(position==0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            getApplicationContex.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Какая ошибка, покажите!

Добавте в вопрос, полный код, и код Manifest.xml

Comment: @Вячеслав если это activity, контекстом выступает она. Значит, реальный код будет выглядеть так:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); // неявно this.startActivity(intent)

Comment: @KirillStoianov applicationContext, насколько я помню, не умеет стартовать activity.

Comment: @Bringoff startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class)); вот так работает , а вот так ошибка getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class));

Comment: @KirillStoianov intent создавать можно и с общим контекстом, а вызывать startActivity() - нет.